# Idiomatic use of 距 and 離

Tags: word-choice

As I try to read Chinese articles, I begin to encounter 距. Some examples are:

> 该列车用的是世界最先进的100%低地板技术，车辆地板距轨道面仅35cm ([TCB](https://www.thechairmansbao.com/worlds-first-hydrogen-tram-enters-commercial-operation-in-hebei/)).
>
> 飛機於距地面一千米處爆炸 (Pleco).
>
> 天津距北京約有一百二十公里 (Pleco)

Is 距 preferred in written Chinese? Is it preferred for vertical distances?

I also found an example that might suggest the two are absolutely interchangeable.

> 距市中心不远的地方就是可以独自滑雪或漫步的林地区域。([Youdao](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E8%B7%9D/#keyfrom=dict2.index))

Comment: 距 is short form for  距離 (distance from); you can replace 距 with 距離 in all the examples you listed

Comment: @TangHo thanks! Does that explain when to prefer it over 離？

Comment: You can also replace 距 with 離 in all the examples above.

Comment: 距 is more literary and  離  is more colloquial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

距 is short form for 距離 (distance from)

- you can replace 距 with 距离 in all the examples you listed.
- You can also replace 距 with 离 in all the examples above.
- 距 is more literary and 离 is more colloquial

S.Gu wrote:

> *However, they are used when expressing distances, doesn’t matter whether vertical or horizontal, you can use either of these three words*

Furthermore, **距离** literally means "**Away from**". It can be used to describe '**distance from**' like all the examples mentioned in the question, and it can also be used to describe '**time till**' For example: "**距离**东京奥运尚有854天"  (still 854 days **away from** Tokyo Olympics = **Time till** Tokyo Olympics is 854 days)

*"离东京奥运尚有854天" is also correct*

*"距东京奥运尚有854天" is not incorrect, but sounds too literal and formal*

Answer (score 1):

距, 离 and 距离, these three can be replaced with each other and would Not change the meaning.
But 距 is slightly more formal, but only slightly. In speaking, 离 and 距离 is used more commonly.

However, they are used when expressing distances, doesn’t matter whether vertical or horizontal, you can use either of these three words

Answer (score 0):

**距、距离、离**：＂汉英虚词词典＂**距（介词）A表示空间的间隔**；宾语多是表示处所的词语，也可是一般体词：１。连队在那～山顶不太远的松林里，为医院设一个临时营地。（王愿坚［普通劳动者］）２。献策如今不在开封，倒是～此地只有二百多里。（姚雪垠［李自成］）３。～礼堂还有几十米远，他便听见一个空瓮似的声音。。。（舜吉［脑科学家的麻烦］）４。李自成同将士们在一起，。。。忽德探马禀报，说看见一股骑兵从兴山方面过来，～此不过十里。（姚雪圻［李自成］）５。最后一排～乐池一百九十四英尺。（报）６。听众～演奏者不宜太近。**B用于时间的间隔**：１。～结婚的时期已近。。。（叶圣陶［倪焕之］）２。在～今五，六万年以前的＂北京人＂的遗物中，有用贝壳缀成的装饰品，用兽牙串成的项练。（报）３。毛主席这一演讲～今已经四十二年了。（报）４。到了韩愈这个时代，上～孔子已经三十八世。。。（郭予衡［杰出的散文学家韩愈］）**C表示抽象意义的差距**：１。有时真理～我们仿佛只有一纸之隔。（报）２。我们的工作～人民的要求还很远。

**参看＂距离＂＂离＂**。

**距离**（介词） **同＇距＂，较＂距＂口语化**：**A 同＂距＂A**：１。官庄～油庄不到两里路。（骆兵基［父女俩］）２。影子～他划的线还有一指多。（王愿坚（普通劳动者］）３。矮个子。。。站在～对方的三步以外。（吴强［红日］）４。这个地方～河槽还有一段地。（刘流［烈火金钢］）５。～高司令近的这伙人是伪省府的高级成员。。。（李英儒［野火春风斗古城］）**B同＂距＂B**：１。现在～二０００年，还有二十一年的时间。（报）２。太早了，～和小华约定的时间还有八个钟头，这八个钟头怎么过呀？（草明［爱情］）３。我认为全部合作化～今天还很远。（王安友［整社基点村的一天］）**C同＂距＂C**：１。我们的政权～一个完全的国家形态还很远。。。（毛泽东［中国革命战争的战略问题］）２。假如果真是这么个用意，～＂现在化＂岂止十万八千里？（叶圣陶［大力研究语文教学，尽快改进语文教学］）３。他原来和我志同道合，可是现在他的思想～我越来越远了。

**离（介词）同＂距＂**，**但很口语化**；**A同＂距＂B**，表示时间的差距：１。现在～开饭的时间还早，你拿点东西给他吃吧。（周而复［上海的早晨］）２。他不过才二十一岁，～他参军的时间不到两年，～他入团的时候不到一年，他怎么有这样伟大的气概，这样叫人感泣的胸怀！（巍巍［这里是今天的东方］）３。可是秋收以后～上冻不到一个月工夫，要是等收完了秋再扩社，扩社完了渠道就不好开了。（赵树理［三里湾］）４。～二十七还有十多天，他完全注意到这一天上去，心里想的，口中念道的，梦中梦见的，全是二十七。（老舍［骆驼祥子］）**B 同＂距＂A**，表示空间的差距：１。现在～最后大的目的地四阜新只有四站地了。（杨朔［秘密列车］）２。姚池～我们县城九十多里，从县城到柳溪还有三十多里，一共是一百多里。（李心田［闪闪的红星］）３。苹果园～花圣地很近，他有两天没去看了，因此他趁着休息时间跑到苹果树地去查看。（李准［林业委员］）４。二发炮弹，落在～第四十四界程碑五百米处。（报）**C同＂距＂C**，表示抽象的差距：１。我们在这方面所做的，～爸爸的希望、党和人民的要求还很远。（报）２。与党的好女儿张志新烈士相比，深感自己～一个共产党员的标准还差得很远。（报）３。＂和你说不成！＂宋老大无可奈何地摆着手，说：＂你这思想呀，～社会主义还差十万八千里哩！＂（西戎［宋老大进城］）